# Comparing sets of values in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to compare two sets of data in the same table to verify an update operation. I've created this query to view the different sets of information side-by-side, but when I add an additional constraint in the `WHERE` clause, I get zero rows returned.

The following query shows me the two record sets next to each other, so I can kinda eyeball that there are different `componentid`s:

```
WITH src AS 
     (SELECT id AS s_id,
             moduleid AS s_moduleid, 
             instanceid AS s_instanceid, 
             tagid AS s_tagid, 
             componentid AS s_componentid 
      FROM component_junction WHERE id=103)
SELECT * FROM component_junction cj 
JOIN src ON s_moduleid=cj.moduleid 
         AND s_instanceid=cj.instanceid 
         AND s_tagid=cj.tagid 
WHERE cj.id=117
```

Returns:

```
id  | moduleid | instanceid | tagid | componentid | s_id | s_moduleid | s_instanceid | s_tagid | s_componentid
----|----------|------------|-------|-------------|------|------------|--------------|---------|--------------
117 | 2923     | 7179       | 1     |   <null>    | 103  | 2923       | 7179         | 1       | <null>
117 | 2923     | 7179       | 2     |   <null>    | 103  | 2923       | 7179         | 2       | <null>
117 | 2924     | 1404       | 1     |   <null>    | 103  | 2924       | 1404         | 1       | <null>
117 | 2924     | 1404       | 2     |   <null>    | 103  | 2924       | 1404         | 2       | <null>
117 | 1        | 41         | 2     |   <null>    | 103  | 1          | 41           | 2       | 267
117 | 1        | 40         | 2     |   <null>    | 103  | 1          | 40           | 2       | 267
117 | 1        | 38         | 2     |   <null>    | 103  | 1          | 38           | 2       | 267
```

But the below query does not return me any rows. Note the extra AND clause at the end:

```
WITH src AS 
     (SELECT id AS s_id,
             moduleid AS s_moduleid, 
             instanceid AS s_instanceid, 
             tagid AS s_tagid, 
             componentid AS s_componentid 
      FROM component_junction WHERE id=103)
SELECT * FROM component_junction cj 
JOIN src ON s_moduleid=cj.moduleid 
         AND s_instanceid=cj.instanceid 
         AND s_tagid=cj.tagid 
WHERE cj.id=117 AND s_componentid != cj.componentid;
```

I know the values are different since I can see it in the result set from the first query. Some NULL values are present in both sets for `componentid` so I'd expect those not to show in the second query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One or both values appear to be `NULL`.  Postgres supports the ANSI standard `NULL` safe comparison, so change

```
s_componentid != cj.componentid
```

to:

```
s_componentid is distinct from cj.componentid
```

Answer (score 0):

As one NULL value differs from another NULL value, you may use ISNULL function  for ComponentID column like below:

```
 WITH src AS 
 (SELECT id AS s_id,
         moduleid AS s_moduleid, 
         instanceid AS s_instanceid, 
         tagid AS s_tagid, 
          ISNULL(componentid,'') AS s_componentid 
  FROM component_junction WHERE id=103)
  SELECT * FROM component_junction cj 
  JOIN src ON s_moduleid=cj.moduleid 
     AND s_instanceid=cj.instanceid 
     AND s_tagid=cj.tagid 
     WHERE cj.id=117 
     AND ISNULL(s_componentid,'') != ISNULL(cj.componentid,'');
```

Comment: Do you mean [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#functions-coalesce-nvl-ifnull)?

Comment: ISNULL function is different than COALESCE. ISNULL replaces null with given value, whereas COALSCE accepts n number of columns as its arguments and gives output by selecting first one of them which is not null. Please do google for more.

Comment: Yep, but `ISNULL` function don't exists on PostgreSQL. You're confusing with SQLServer. See question tags.